# Webgl 2.0 unsupported in chrome

Tags: webgl2

My chrome shows Webgl 2.0 - supported, but disabled in browser settings, or blocked by extensions.
I have tried 
1. Use hardware acceleration in chrome://settings
2. Enabled WEBGL 2.0 in chrome://flags
3. Override software render list ..
What other option are out there to enable webgl 2.0 from browser settings?
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Since some months WebGL 2 is enabled by default. I recomend checking that your chrome is up to date first. Then check the site: chrome://gpu/ Especially the `GL_RENDERER` and `GL_VERSION` list entries. Be shure you support OpenGL ES 3.0

Comment: As Bellian mentioned it's possible your computer/tablet/phone doesn't have the hardware to support WebGL2. Update your drivers if there are newer versions and as Bellian mentioned check "about:gpu" for info

Comment: Chrome version in my 61.0.3163. Webgl 1.0 works fine in chrome..The problem is with webgl 2.0. i guess hardware may not be the problem, since i am able to run webgl 2.0 samples in firefox with the same machine.

Comment: My GL_RENDERER is "ANGLE (Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 Direct3D9Ex vs_3_0 ps_3_0)" & GL_VERSION is OpenGL ES 2.0. for chrome

Answer (score 2):

It seems current ANGLE (which is [OpenGL emulation using DirectX driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANGLE_(software))) does not support WebGL2 unless running on DirectX 11. You need to select a different back-end.

Open chrome://flags/ and search for "Angle". You should see an option called **Choose ANGLE graphics backend**

If the value you see is **DirectX 9**, choose **OpenGL** or **DirectX 11** instead.

You can confirm that everything works fine by going to [WebGLReport](https://webglreport.com/?v=2), which will also show you which driver is used and what capabilities or OpenGL extensions can be used.

Beware: depending on your graphics card and drivers you have installed it is possible Chrome will switch to a software rasterizer. In WebGLReport you will see "Major Performance Caveat:   Yes" in such case and following info about the renderer:

- Renderer: WebKit WebGL
- Unmasked Vendor:  Google Inc.
- Unmasked Renderer:    Google SwiftShader

You can also find some information about how Chrome is using your graphics card by opening the chrome://gpu/ page.

There was one more step I had to do to make WebGL 2 / Direct3D 11 working correctly on my computer (I am using a few years old nVidia GeForce GT 545): I had to uninstall nVidia  Nsight, as it was interfering in some way with the drivers. I have seen a similar thing reported by other people [nVidia forums: Failed to initialize D3D11 device ...](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/game-ready-drivers/13/284660/failed-to-initialize-d3d11-device-on-various-progr/2075591/):

> 1. Installed the nvidia drivers (without uninstalling or cleaning first) with all the extra software that comes with the driver, as "checked". Didn't reboot after installation.

> 2. Uninstalled all the extra nvidia software (3D vision, Update, HD audio etc) from Control Panel\Programs and Features. Left only the driver and PhysX.

> 3. Reboot.

---

[image]

Comment: The option to change ANGLE graphics backend does not appear on my browser

Answer (score 0):

Try starting Chrome with the command line flag `--use-angle=gl`.

It tells the ANGLE renderer to use the OpenGL backend, which may expose more features of your card than the default Direct3D9 backend. This solved the same issue for my GeForce GTX 560 Ti.